# Installing a handmade puppet module changed in Debian stretch

Tags: puppet

In debian jessie, I used to install my own handmyde puppet module in a subfolder in `/etc/puppet/modules`. I simply created a foder there with git:

```
cd /etc/puppet/modules
git clone https://github.com/ffnord/ffnord-puppet-gateway ffnord
```

from then on, I could use the module `ffnord` in my puppet scripts.

This does not work in Debian stretch any more. How can I install my module in Debaian 9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modules folder changed to

```
/etc/puppet/code/modules
```

You find out with

```
$ sudo puppet config print modulepath 
/etc/puppet/code/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules
```

A better path would be `/usr/share/puppet/modules`.

see https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/dirs_modulepath.html